# gdal and ThreadPoolExecutor -- thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, gdal, threadpoolexecutor

I have just discovered a strange issue whereby `gdal` and `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` don't play nicely. Specifically, we are ending up with a huge variation in file sizes, even though the final files contain valid data.

A minimal working example looks like this:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

sz = 256 * 8
n_bands = 35
img = np.random.uniform(0.0, 256.0, size=(sz, sz, n_bands)).astype(np.uint8)
n_tifs = 150

def make_tif(i):
    outfile = f'data/tmp/{i}.tif'
    options = [
        'COMPRESS=LZW',
        'TILED=YES',
        'PREDICTOR=2',
        'COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES',
    ]
    dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(outfile, sz, sz, n_bands, gdal.GDT_Byte, options=options)
    for j in range(n_bands):
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(j + 1).WriteArray(img[j])
    dst_ds.FlushCache()
    del dst_ds

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_tifs) as e:
    e.map(make_tif, range(n_tifs))

sizes = [Path(f'data/tmp/{i}.tif').stat().st_size / (1 << 20) for i in range(n_tifs)]
print(min(sizes), max(sizes))
```

That results in: `4.914698600769043 31.87781810760498` -- i.e. saving the exact same numpy array produces tiffs that vary in size by an order of magnitude.

Switching the `ThreadPoolExecutor` for a `ProcessPoolExecutor` gives a final output of `3.7290191650390625 3.7290191650390625` which exactly what you get if you don't run it in parallel.

Does anyone know the reason why `gdal` is not thread safe? Or are we using it in a way that is incorrect?

**EDIT**

This code will *fix* the bad files

```py
def apply_fix(filepath, new_filepath):
    ds = gdal.Open(filepath)
    options = [
        'COMPRESS=LZW',
        'TILED=YES',
        'PREDICTOR=2',
        'COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES',
    ]
    ds = gdal.Translate(new_filepath, ds, creationOptions=options)
    del ds
```

Answer (score 0):

Its number of bands as far as I can tell .. I tried upto 20 and its as per expectations with `ThreadPoolExecutor` but # bands 25 starts to give me different results. I would guess its something to do with PREDICTOR=2 and # bands. 
Need some gdal experts with this question .. might be worth raising it in gdal github IMO. I tested on `gdal 2.4.2`